# Passing and updating chef node attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I am looking at the option of creating a LWRP for some common function we are using in our cookbooks. Is there a way to pass a node attribute and update it in LWRP?

The second option is to create library functions. If a node attribute is passed by the caller to the library function, how to go about setting a new value in the function?

Any pointers to these are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really need more details to answer with much certainty.

## If you are just reading and setting attributes

Then you'll want to use a library function rather than a resource/provider.  You don't have to "pass" anything, as the `node` object is already available inside both libraries and LWRPs.  You can access the attributes the same way you always do with `node['path']['to']['attribute']`  and set them the same as in a recipe with `node.default['path']['to']['attribute']`  (or `.normal`, `.override`, etc).  If you wanted to be really fancy, and make the method variable, you could do something like this.

*untested code (takes a path to an attribute, and sets that attribute to the return value of a block, passing the current value of the attribute into the block)

```
def check_and_set(*attr_path, &check)
  current, parent = node
  leaf = nil
  current = attr_path.reduce do |current, branch| 
    current[branch]
    parent = current
    leaf = branch 
  value = check.yield(current)
  parent[leaf] = value
end
```

## If you are doing something with the value

If you're not just reading an setting, then you may need an LWRP.  Everything stated above still applies.  The `node` object is still available and you can read from and write to it just as you would in a recipe.

Comment: Also, you might find `node` at the time your library is loaded is not the data you expect. It's always a better practice to pass the node object into library functions, so that you are getting `node` at the time of the call, not at compile time, or potentially before any cookbooks are even loaded that override node values.

Comment: Thanks Tejay & Martin.